# TensorFlow For Poets tf_iles/retraine_labels.txt not found

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am new to the domain of machine learning and neural networks.
I was following along the CodeLabs TensorFlow for Poets Tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html#3
While trying to test an Image against my retrained model, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "label_image.py", line 15, in <module>
in tf.gfile.GFile("retrained_labels.txt")]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 164, in next
retval = self.readline()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 133, in readline
self._preread_check()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 75, in _preread_check
compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
self.gen.next()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in 
raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: retrained_labels.txt
```

I am assuming it has something to do with the retrained_label.txt file that is created while retraining the model
So I checked the working directory and the retrained_label.txt file was missing
Can someone please help me fix this

Answer (score 0):

The `retrained_labels.txt` file should have been created by the step where you ran `retrain.py`. Can you try re-running this to see if you can successfully create it, or if there's an error at that point?